# Android ;download file from PC using DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, file, tomcat, download

I following this tutorials http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

to use Download files located on my Personal Computer

I change the url to  `http://@ip:8080/files/tests.txt`

Mu files are located on the  `ROOT` folder within `webapps` (I am using apache tomcat)

but download is never started !

the url work fine with other app (to interrogate a servlet for example)

what is the problem? and how can i download file located on my pc ?